# How to compare elements of array in mips assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I know how to iterate through an array in mips. However I can't seem to figure out how to compare two elements in the same array? Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

```
if(array[i] > array[i - 3])
```

I believe it would be a branch if greater than comparing two registers but how would I get the data into the two registers? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your question isn't about comparing, rather it's about loading an item from an array ... you can do that with the `lw` instruction (or friends, if you don't have word size items). You might want to remember that C `array[i]` is equivalent to `*(array + i)` and that C scales by item size automatically but asm doesn't. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491018/mips-getting-array-values/28491385).

Answer (score 0):

You cant just iterate an array... You have to add a multiple of 4 (=> index * 4) to the memory address of the array. Then you can load the value at this modified memory addres and compair it to a diffrent moddified addres...

```
.data
array: .word 1,2,3

#Index's you want to compair
i1: .word 0
i2: .word 1 

.text

MAIN:
lw $a0 i1
lw $a1 i2
li $t5 4 #load multiplier
mul $a0 $a0 $t5
mul $a1 $a1 $t5

la $t0 array
la $t1 array

add $t0 $t0 $a0
add $t1 $t1 $a1

lw $t0 ($t0)
lw $t1 ($t1)

beq $t0 $t1 TRUE
```